# How do I prevent lists inside a dict from splitting into rows when converting to DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following:

```
a = {
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "list": ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
}
DataFrame(a)
*****Output*****
                      url list
0  http://www.example.com  abc
1  http://www.example.com  def
2  http://www.example.com  ghi
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
                      url             list
0  http://www.example.com  [abc, def, ghi]
```

How do I get the intended output? I tried converting `a["list"]` into a `DataFrame`, `DataFrame(a, index=[0])` and other ideas from Googling, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your list inside a list.

```
a = {
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "list": [["abc", "def", "ghi"]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

Use `groupby` and `apply` with the `list` function to get your desired output:

```
df.groupby('url')['list'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

---

```
                      url             list
0  http://www.example.com  [abc, def, ghi]
```

---

## Method 2

Using the `aggregate` function

```
df.groupby('url', as_index=False).agg({'list':list})
```

---

```
                      url             list
0  http://www.example.com  [abc, def, ghi]
```